# What, if any, options are there for full web (rather than mobile-based) semantics for an iPad Pro be based?

Tags: ios, ipad, google-chrome, desktop, mobile-safari

I am the not-entirely-proud owner of a new iPad Pro. The screen size is comparable to a perhaps slightly low-end midsize laptop, and larger than netbook range (which run standard OSes and standard desktop browsers). I am finding, to my annoyance, that websites' responsive design classifies this device as mobile and therefore offers a <del>dumbed-down</del> streamlined mobile experience, meaning that often the features of websites I want to use are not available because they did not meet the mobile prioritized cut.

I know there is (or at least was) FakeWeb, a browser that lets you specify your own user-agent string; and I know as a web professional that websites are supposed to let people choose between full web and mobile versions, but I can't find the option on Gmail.

What are my options if I want to use full web (desktop) features from my iPad? Anything besides FakeWeb?

Comment: Since you only get 5 tags - are you more interested in a software recommendation? If so, let's clean up things - perhaps removing desktop and chrome and possibly mobile safari if they don't work for your needs...

Comment: I'll happily take the iPad Pro off your hands. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the OP's question,

> "What are my options if I want to use full web (desktop) features from
>   my iPad? Anything besides FakeWeb?"

In Mobile Safari for iOS 9.x, if you wish to see the desktop version of a given website, do the following.

- After navigating to the website, select the **share button**.  (Square with a arrow pointing up out of it.)
- Select **Request Desktop Site**

There are some stubborn websites (Google for instance) but most sites should be responsive.

---

### Before

[image: Request Desktop Site]

---

### After

[image: Desktop Site Mobile Safari iOS 9.x]

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard for communicating to all web servers that you want a desktop render when you are using Mobile Safari. As you probably know, the agent string is used by almost all web sites to decide which code base to serve and with javascript, you will have some web sites making drastic changes to what you see based on what they "detect" your browser.

The pragmatic approaches are to deal with sites you have to and hope that the developers see enough traffic from the iPad Pro to invest the time to make their products take better advantage of the area and performance that browser offers.

Gmail is pretty quick to react to improving their site as they make money with your eyeballs and are highly incentivized to get you to use their service. Hopefully you might not have to wait that long for them to code their site to take advantage of mobile safari on iPad Pro.